# java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Java cannot find my dll's?

Tags: java, r

I am developing a program that calls [R](http://www.r-project.org/) functions from Java using JRI/rJava. I was coding the program in NetBeans on another machine, which was working fine (i.e. able to run the code). I have since then moved to another machine and have been running into problems.

The exact error message I am seeing is this:

```
Cannot find JRI native library!
Please make sure that the JRI native library is in a directory listed in java.library.path.
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: E:\R\R-2.13.1\library\rJava\jri\jri.dll: The specified path is invalid
    at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(ClassLoader.java:1807)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1732)
    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:823)
    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1028)
    at org.rosuda.JRI.Rengine.<clinit>(Rengine.java:19)
    at com.rjava.test.rtest.main(rtest.java:64)
Java Result: 1
```

I have read the FAQs for JRI/rJava, and have been scouring the internet for fixes, but have made no progress. Here is what I have done so far:

- Created an environment variable called R_HOME: "E:\R\R-2.13.1"
- Added "%R_HOME%\bin\x64" to the PATH environment variable
- Added "%R_HOME%\library\rJava\JRI" to the PATH environment variable (this is where jri.dll is located)
- Set the required jar files as compile time libraries (JRI.jar, JRIEngine.jar, REngine.jar) in NetBeans
- set the following VM options in NetBeans: : -Djava.library.path=E:\R\R-2.13.1\library\rJava\jri (This is where jri.dll is located)

I have restarted my computer to make sure that the changes stick.

To make sure I configured things correctly, I ran the following in the command line:

```
java -cp E:\R\R-2.13.1\library\rJava\jri\JRI.jar;E:\R\R-2.13.1\library\rJava\jri\examples rtest
```

And the example java files ran fine. I'm beginning to think my new machine just hates me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The message indicates that it the path E:\R\R-2.13.1\library\rJava\jri\jri.dll is invalid. Are you sure that path exists? Also, is E a mapped drive that is mapped to a path that has spaces in it? I'm not sure if the spaces are the issue, but it eliminates one issue. I would try just putting the dll in C:\ or somewhere very simple and seeing if it can find it there as a simple test.

Also verify that the -Djava.library.path is being passed as you think it is (you can check that with visualvm or jconsole).

Comment: E: is a network drive, I set it up so that I can access my work from any machine, and it may be the cause of my problems. I will have to investigate that tomorrow. I have switched to my old machine (which has all the files locally) for the rest of the day (due to frustration), but I think you may be right. I will change everything to a local drive and see if things work.

Answer (score 1):

You could try this:

```
-Djava.library.path=E:\R\R-2.13.1\library\rJava\jri -cp E:\R\R-2.13.1\library
\rJava\jri;E:\R\R-2.13.1\library\rJava\jri\JRI.jar;E:\R\R-2.13.1
\library\rJava\jri\examples
```

The reason I say this is that, perhaps the .dll also needs to be in the classpath as well as the library path in order for the classloader to load it?   Its probably not true, but worth trying.  Also is "rJava" correct?  Other than that, it looks to me like your doing it right.

Comment: Thanks, I will give that a try tomorrow. "rJava" is correct, I triple checked all the directories to make sure everything was where it should be. I have switched to my old machine for the rest of the day out of frustration.

Comment: If you have MSSQL server, you could write a small test program using the sqljdbc.jar + the corresponding .dll that goes with it and see if you are able to get that simple test case working.  Of course, using the JDBC option: integratedSecurity=true to the jdbc driver.  If you can get that working, then you know that your methodology should be correct. (requires: enable sa account, set its password, enable sql authentication in the sql instance, and enable port 1433 listener).  Also, put the .dll in a totally separate dir somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

To locate JRI installed with rJava, use `system.file("jri",package="rJava")` in R.

set that path to your path (environment variables in windows),
restart your netbeans. and try to run your program again